# How can I combine Select2 tagging with DataTables regex filtering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, datatables, jquery-select2

I'm trying to filter a jquery DataTables table with keyword/tags entered through a Select2 tagging interface using the regex filter so I can filter on OR instead of exact match.

I'm initializing the DataTables with the separator set to pipe | (regex OR) but it's still separating the tags with commas in the value attribute of the input.

```
jQuery('#programs-table').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "bPaginate": false,
            "separator": "|"
          });
jQuery("#program-filter-keyword").change( fnFilterGlobal );
```

Even if I manually change the search field it doesn't always filter with OR, mostly when using two word tags or tags with a comma like the 'protection, security...' - I think I can get around the 'separator' option not working as it should by using replace on the input value to turn commas to pipes although that's not ideal as some tags have commas and I also need to replace spaces and comma+spaces with their regex counterparts to make it work.

```
function fnFilterGlobal () {
          jQuery('#programs-table').dataTable().fnFilter(
            jQuery("#program-filter-keyword").val().replace(',','|'),
            null,
            true,
            true
          );              
        }
```

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Does anyone know the proper way to set this up to use tags from select2 as an OR filter on datatables
2. I'm new with regex - is there a way to convert what Select2 is inputting as the input value for the tags into a proper regex OR search including the tags with spaces/commas?

Here is a CodePen (jsFiddle is down) of an example. http://codepen.io/tsdexter/pen/GcnxA

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this which is, so far, working in all use cases I've tested.

I'm basically bypassing the value that Select2 passes to the hidden input field since it messes up the commas due to the 'separator' option not actually changing the separator for tags-mode (it only works with multi-select inputs).

Here is the filtering function:

```
function fnFilterGlobal () {             
    var tags = [];
    jQuery("#s2id_program-filter-keyword .select2-search-choice div").each(function() { 
        tags.push(jQuery(this).text()); 
    });              
    jQuery('#programs-table').dataTable().fnFilter(
        tags.join("|").replace(/ /g,"\\ "), null, true, false
    );              
}
```

I'm building an array of the selected tags by parsing the `<ul>` list that Select2 creates and extracting the tags values from the `<div>` content.

Then for the actual filter string I've joined the array items with the pipe symbol for the OR functionality and replaced all spaces with `\` (escaped space).

Lastly, I set the 'smart filter' option to `false` - this is key, otherwise it will try to turn the filter string into a complicated regex which I've already made it one and the escaped spaces cause invalid regex errors.

I've updated the CodePen so you can see how to have multi tag OR filterable tables using Select2 and DataTables http://codepen.io/tsdexter/pen/GcnxA